# Jquery menu not working in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I have a website, I have used :

http://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly

as my navigation.
However everything works, but when i make the browser smaller I try opening the navigation and it doesn't open. after hours of investigation, there is a problem in this Jquery script.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#mobileMenu').append('<div id="nav" role="navigation">' + $('#mainNav').html() + '</div>');
        $('#nav').append('<div style="position:absolute;top:0px; right:0px;"></div>');
        $('#mainNav').html('');
    });
```

any ideas on where I might be going wrong.

#nav is the class that opens the menu, but i need this code on my site but i think i may be missing something.

Comment: well .. I tested your DEMO (http://osvaldas.info/examples/drop-down-navigation-touch-friendly-and-responsive/?home) , and worked well in Firefox, at all resolutions ..  I think you have troubles on tables .. no !? be more explicit ..

Comment: thats not my demo. that is the example i want to copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript to handle click on menu icon:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if(jQuery(window).width() < 661) {
        $('#nav').find('.desktopNone').eq(0).unbind('click');
        $('#nav').find('.desktopNone').eq(0).on('click', function() {
            if($('#nav').find('ul').eq(0).css('display') == 'none') {
                $('#nav').find('ul').eq(0).show();
            } else {
                $('#nav').find('ul').eq(0).hide();
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#nav').find('ul').eq(0).show();
    }
});
```

CSS to make it looking good:

```
media="all"
@media only screen and (max-width: 40em)
#nav > ul {
    height: auto;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #F1F1F1;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: i added the code, but the #nav link is still not working, have a look at the updated code on the website

Comment: i want to open a the #nav bar to show the menu... and not have it displayed automatically.

Comment: check now (added window resize event handler and css display)

Comment: i have added everything you given me, but it still not working, i think its something to do with the 3 line of code that i posted...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of body load function use window re size function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#mobileMenu').append('<div id="nav" role="navigation">' + $('#mainNav').html() + '</div>');
       $('#nav').append('<div style="position:absolute;top:0px; right:0px;"></div>');
          $('#mainNav').html('');
});
```

Css

```
.hivMenuLi a
{
    color: #ed917b;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    width: 52px !important;
    margin-right: 8px;
}

.hcvMenuLi a
{
    color: #ffc72a;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    width: 115px !important;
    margin-right: 8px;
}

.oncologyMenuLi a
{
    color: #624c79;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    ;
    margin-right: -8px;
    margin-right: 6px;
}

.homeLi a
{
    color: #808184;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    width: 61px auto;
    margin-right: 8px;
}

.aboutLi a
{
    color: #808184;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 4px;
    width: 74px !important;
}


#nav > a
{
    display: none;
}

#nav > p
{
    display: none;
}



.clearfix > li
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

    .clearfix > li > ul
    {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        width: 130px;
        background-color: grey;
    }

    .clearfix > li:hover > ul
    {
        display: block;
    }

.clearfix > .hivMenuLi:hover > a
{
    color: white;
    background-color: #ed917b;
}

.clearfix > .hcvMenuLi:hover > a
{
    color: white;
    background-color: #ffc72a;
}

.clearfix > .oncologyMenuLi:hover > a
{
    color: white;
    background-color: #624c79;
}

.clearfix > .aboutLi:hover > a
{
    color: white;
    background-color: #808184;
}


.clearfix > li a
{
    width: 105px;
    display: block;
    font-family: Helvetica-Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.clearfix > li
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

    .clearfix > li > ul
    {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
    }

    .clearfix > li:hover > ul
    {
        display: block;
    }

    .clearfix > li:hover a
    {
        color: #54565b;
    }

    .clearfix > li > ul > li:hover
    {
    }

    .clearfix > li > ul > li > a
    {
        font-family: Helvetica-Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: normal;
        padding: 2px 12px;
        line-height: 24px;
        width: 130px !important;
        display: block !important;
        z-index: 99999;
    }

        .clearfix > li > ul > li > a:hover
        {
            color: white;
            font-family: Helvetica-Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: normal;
            padding: 2px 12px;
            display: inline;
        }

    .clearfix > li > ul
    {
        background-color: #e6e6e6;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 9px -2px rgba(26,26,26,1);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 9px -2px rgba(26,26,26,1);
        box-shadow: 4px 7px 9px -2px rgba(26,26,26,1);
        border-bottom: 3px solid #54565b;
        width: 159px !important;
        z-index: 1;
    }

.hivMenuLi > ul > li:hover
{
    background-color: #ed917b;
}

.hcvMenuLi > ul > li:hover
{
    background-color: #ffc72a;
}

.oncologyMenuLi > ul > li:hover
{
    background-color: #624c79;
}

.aboutLi > ul > li:hover
{
    background-color: #808184;
}

#oncologyMenu
{
    margin-right: -7px;
}
/*.clearfix > li .hivMenuLi
        {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
        }

            .clearfix > li .hivMenuLi > ul
            {
                display: inline-block;
                position: absolute;
                display: none;
            }

            .clearfix > li .hivMenuLi:hover > ul
            {
                display: block;
            }

            .clearfix > li .hivMenuLi:hover a, .clearfix > li .hivMenuLi:hover span
            {
                color: #000;

            }
        .clearfix > li > ul > li > a
        {
            color: #000;
        }
        .clearfix > li > ul > li > a:hover
        {
            color:#000;
        }
        .clearfix > li > ul
        {
            background-color: white;
        }
        .hivMenuLi > ul > li:hover
        {
            background-color: pink;
        }*/

@media only screen and (min-width:769px)
{
    .desktopmenu
    {
        float: right;
        /*margin-left: 550px;*/
        float: right;
position: relative;
top: 97px;
    }
}


@media only screen and ( max-width: 62.5em ) /* 1000 */
{
    #nav
    {
        width: 100%;
        position: static;
        margin: 0;
    }
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 40em ) /* 640 */
{
    html
    {
        font-size: 75%; /* 12 */
    }

    #nav
    {
        position: relative;
        top: auto;
        left: auto;
    }

        #nav > a
        {
            width: 3.125em; /* 50 */
            height: 3.125em; /* 50 */
            text-align: left;
            text-indent: -9999px;
            background-color: grey;
            position: absolute;
            top: 5px !important;
            right: 7px;
        }

        #nav > p
        {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: #e4e4e4;
            line-height: 50px;
            font-size: 21px;
            color: black;
            font-weight: bold;
        }


        #nav > a:before,
        #nav > a:after
        {
            position: absolute;
            border: 2px solid #fff;
            top: 35%;
            left: 25%;
            right: 25%;
            content: '';
        }

        #nav > a:after
        {
            top: 60%;
        }


        #nav:not( :target ) > a:first-of-type,
        #nav:target > a:last-of-type
        {
            display: block;
        }


        /* first level */

        #nav > ul
        {
           height: auto;
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;

        }

        #nav:target > ul
        {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
        }

        #nav > ul > li
        {
            width: 100%;
            float: none;
        }

            #nav > ul > li > a
            {
                height: auto;
                text-align: left;
                /*padding: 0 0.833em; /* 20 (24) */ */;
            }

            #nav > ul > li:not( :last-child ) > a
            {
                border-right: none;
                padding: 6px;
            }


        /* second level */

        #nav li ul
        {
            position: static;
            padding-top: 0;
            width: 95% !important;
            line-height: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

    .clearfix > li > ul
    {
        background-color: #e6e6e6;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 9px -2px rgba(26,26,26,1);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 9px -2px rgba(26,26,26,1);
        box-shadow: 4px 7px 9px -2px rgba(167, 163, 163, 1);
        border-bottom: 3px solid #54565b;
    }
}
```

Comment: that dont work, this use to work, but because of these 3 lines of code it stopped, the reason i have added these was because it has to be on top of the page for the navigation to work... add your code makes me go back to square one as it keeps jumping around

Comment: instead of showing me the whole css can you tell me what you changed. the jquery looks the same...

Comment: you copied code from another website. U missed stylesheet of menus `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/css/menus.css" />`